# unable to fetch data from web page - dom query

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I used that code to automatically fetch some fields from the website and fill the excel table with search results but I think something changed on the website and I can not get this code working again...any help, suggestions?

```
Sub Scramble_NAVY_search()

Dim cel As Range, ms As Worksheet, dom As HTMLDocument
Set ms = Sheets("Scramble")
'Const searchUrl = "http://www.scramble.nl/index.php?option=com_mildb&view=search"

For Each cel In ms.Range("B2:B" & ms.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(2)
    Set dom = New HTMLDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
        .Open "POST", searchUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "Itemid=60&af=usn&serial=" & cel & "&sbm=Search&code=&searchtype=&unit=&cn="
        dom.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    With cel
        If .Offset(, -1).Value = "" Then
            .Offset(, 2) = dom.getElementsByClassName("rowBord")(0).Cells(1).innerText 'Code
            .Offset(, -1) = dom.getElementsByClassName("rowBord")(0).Cells(2).innerText 'Type
            .Offset(, 10) = dom.getElementsByClassName("rowBord")(0).Cells(3).innerText 'C/N
            .Offset(, 3) = dom.getElementsByClassName("rowBord")(0).Cells(4).innerText 'Unit
            .Offset(, 11) = dom.getElementsByClassName("rowBord")(0).Cells(5).innerText 'Status
        End If
    End With
   Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the code with `F8` and see which line gives you an error. You have provided some code, but not specified what output you expect (or what data you want to get from the website). If I navigate to `https://www.scramble.nl/?option=com_mildb&view=search&Itemid=60&af=usn&serial=&sbm=Search&code=&searchtype=&unit=&cn=` in my browser, I see a bunch of search fields (but no class named `rowBord` in the page's HTML or CSS).

Comment: I suspect you have commented out the searchUrl declaration on purpose, right? Because it's definitely not going to work like that..

Comment: Commented out line was my pasting error, I was trying different options before I posted the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the line where your `searchUrl` is being declared, has been commented out. I am not sure if this was done knowingly and on purpose. So start by deleting `'` in front of `Const searchUrl`.

Secondly, change your `searchUrl` to this (basically change http to https):

> https://www.scramble.nl/index.php?option=com_mildb&view=search

Finally, I have edited the code formatting in your post. Accept the edits and use that formatting. There were some line breaks there that would give an error.

You should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more efficient re-write. I move the creation of the `winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1` and  `dom` objects out of the loop to avoid continually creating and destroying. Moved `Screenupdating` out so only handled at start and finish. Set the record returned, and loop range, into variables so you access from that.

Normally, I would work with loading the values to loop over into an array and looping the array. I would store results in an array and write out once at end as constantly touching the sheet is expensive. As I do not know what is happening in the other columns, and it seems like there can be gaps in your data range I haven't done these amendments.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ScrambleNavySearch()
    Dim cel As Range, ms As Worksheet, dom As HTMLDocument, loopRange As Range
    Const SEARCH_URL As String = "https://www.scramble.nl/index.php?option=com_mildb&view=search"

    Set ms = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scramble")
    Set dom = New HTMLDocument
    Set loopRange = ms.Range("B2:B" & ms.Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")

        For Each cel In loopRange

            .Open "POST", SEARCH_URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .send "Itemid=60&af=usn&serial=" & cel & "&sbm=Search&code=&searchtype=&unit=&cn="
            dom.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Dim recordFields As Object

            Set recordFields = dom.querySelectorAll(".rowBord td")

            If recordFields.Length > 0 Then
                With cel
                    .Offset(, -1) = recordFields.item(2).innerText 'Type
                    .Offset(, 2) = recordFields.item(1).innerText 'Code
                    .Offset(, 3) = recordFields.item(4).innerText 'Unit
                    .Offset(, 10) = recordFields.item(3).innerText 'C/N
                    .Offset(, 11) = recordFields.item(5).innerText 'Status
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```